# "find" specific contents [linux]

Tags: linux, find, command

I would like to go through all the files in the current directory (or sub-directories) and echoes me back the name of files only if they contain certain words.

More detail:

find -type f -name "*hello *" will give me all file names that have "hello" in their names. But instead of that, I want to search through the files and if that file's content contains "hello" then prints out the name of the file.

Is there a way to approach this?

Comment: `find -type f -exec grep -l hello {} + ` or install [the silver sarcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GNU `find` and GNU `grep` as

```
find /path -type f -exec grep -Hi 'hello' {} +
```

This is efficient in a way that it doesn't invoke as many `grep` instances to as many files returned from `find`. This works in an underlying assumption that `find` returns a set of files for `grep` to search on. If you are unsure if the files may not be available, as a fool-proof way, you can use `xargs` with `-r` flag, in which case the commands following `xargs` are executed only if the piped commands return any results

```
find /path -type f | xargs -r0 grep -Hi 'hello'
```

Comment: Thank you! But in the first example, what does {} + exactly do?

Comment: Please read this [find man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) under the section `-exec command {} +` and this http://www.softpanorama.org/Tools/Find/using_exec_option_and_xargs_in_find.shtml . I would literally quote from these pages for explanation :)